# Center Arrows Vertically On Both Sides of Div

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, position, css-position

I've got two items I can't figure out. I'm trying to center both arrows shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3af4.jpg) on either side of the div box (no matter what the height, they are always centered). The box is min-height and I need the arrows to be centered depending on the height of the box.

Also, when the media screen kicks in, I want them to always display on the left and right no matter where the user has scrolled.  I don't have a clue how to keep them in place when the user scrolls.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

CSS

```
#recout{
text-align:center;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
.recleft,
.recright{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 550px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.recin{
    background: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-height: 550px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 70px 70px 0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id= "recout">

<div class= "recleft"> 
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle fill="#9FA1A4" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M31.2,8.4c1,0,2,0.4,2.8,1c0.9,0.7,1.4,1.8,1.4,2.9c0,1.1-0.5,2.2-1.4,2.9l-11.8,10l11.8,10
        c0.9,0.7,1.4,1.8,1.4,2.9s-0.5,2.1-1.4,2.9c-1.5,1.3-4,1.3-5.5,0L13.2,28.1c-0.9-0.7-1.4-1.8-1.4-2.9c0-1.1,0.5-2.1,1.4-2.9
        L28.4,9.4C29.2,8.8,30.2,8.4,31.2,8.4z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class= "recin"></div>

<div class= "recright">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle fill="#9FA1A4" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M20,42c-1,0-2-0.4-2.8-1c-0.9-0.7-1.4-1.8-1.4-2.9c0-1.1,0.5-2.2,1.4-2.9l11.8-10l-11.8-10
        c-0.9-0.7-1.4-1.8-1.4-2.9s0.5-2.1,1.4-2.9c1.5-1.3,4-1.3,5.5,0L38,22.3c0.9,0.7,1.4,1.8,1.4,2.9c0,1.1-0.5,2.1-1.4,2.9L22.7,41
        C22,41.7,21,42,20,42z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when the media screen kicks in"? When your window is below a certain size?

Comment: Yes, Sorry. I didn't clarify that.  at mobile screen size, it will keep the buttons on the left and right, no matter where the user has scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you want the svg to be vertically centerd inside the .recleft and .recright respectively.

To do that use `position: absolute` on a wrapper around the svg (it looks weird when applying it directly to the svg), set `top: 50%`, this will center the div, and finally apply `position: relative` to the parent so that the wrapper div is absolutely positioned relative to this parent. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgn6gqju/)

For the problem with the mobile view you would need to set `position: fixed;` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/m9xqnh8y/1/

And for the problem that if the `.recin` gains in height. I made a flexbox containing `recleft`, `recin` and `recright`, this way the other divs automatically take up the full height and thus the arrows also remain in the middle. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/08wo4hL8/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This definitely helps with the first part of the problem.  When the media screen is, let's say, 320px wide, how do I keep the svg's static in the div while they are scrolling?

Comment: Actually - I'm having issues when the content within the recin class is larger than the min-height, the svg's aren't expanding the height when the recin class is higher than the min-height.

Comment: I hope this answered your questions now :)